# what is a domain error

Tags: c++, stl

in c++, <stdexcept> has a base class for 'domain errors', std::domain_error.  i don't understand under what circumstances i should throw a domain error in my code.  all of the other exception base classes are pretty self explanatory.  i'm pretty sure that std::domain_error has nothing to do with internet domain names, per se, so please explain what class of error a domain error is and provide some examples.

Comment: so i'm seeing lots of responses about mathematical domains, e.g. sqrt(-1) should throw a domain_error (unless of course you implement complex numbers).  how is this different from range_error?  before your answers, i would have considered sqrt(-1) to be a range_error.

Comment: It should be noted that no c++ standard library function throws a domain error. It is intended for the end user.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Domain and range errors are both used when dealing with mathematical functions.

On the one hand, the domain of a function is the set of values that can be accepted by the function. For example, the domain of the root square function is the set of positive real numbers. Therefore, a [`domain_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/domain_error) exception is to be thrown when the arguments of a function are not contained in its domain

On the other hand, the range of a function is the set of values that the function can return. For example, the range of a function like this one:

```
f(x) = -x²
```

is the set of negative real numbers. So what is the point of the `range_error`? If the arguments of the function are in its domain, then the result must be in its range, so we shouldn't have any errors wrt the range...However, sometimes the value can be *defined*, but without being *representable*. For example, in C, the functions in `<math.h>` generate errors if the return value is too large (or too small) in magnitude to represent

Comment: I wonder if it is standard or reprehensible to throw domain_error and range_error in non-mathematical functions, to represent the same error conditions (argument_error rather than domain_error perhaps?)

Comment: @fuzzyTew: As a matter of fact, the standard library contains a class [`invalid_argument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcs4t8fy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so you should probably use that instead :)!

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation of when to use the exception. Your view on range_error is also interesting. As [cpplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/range_error/) states it's for "range errors in internal computations". It is even placed in runtime errors group...

Comment: ...And the return value being too large or too small to be representable by the machine is exactly a runtime error. With the same way of thinking I can also see this exception being used when a function makes step by step calculations and even while both function domain and function ranges are ok, it still can get out of range somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 6):

A *domain error* refers to issues with *mathematical domains* of functions. Functions are sometimes defined only for certain values. If you try to invoke such a function with an argument that is not part of its domain, that is a domain error.

For example, trying to invoke `sqrt()` with a negative argument is a domain error, since negative numbers are not part of the domain of `sqrt()`.

Comment: But when I do sqrt(-1) it returns nan and doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty good explanation form [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/stdexcept/domain_error.html):

> Generally, the domain of a mathematical function is the subset of values that it is defined for. For example, the square root function is only defined for non-negative numbers. Thus, a negative number for such a function would be a domain error.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is all the guidance you get from the C++ standard:

> The class domain_error defines the
>   type of objects thrown as exceptions
>   by the implementation to report domain
>   errors.

Domain here means "problem domain", nothing to do with the internet. For example, a square root function might throw a domain error if passed a negative number.

Answer (score 2):

It's for logic errors of the class of "domain" errors. This could apply to any situation where the input to a function exceeds the allowable domain for it to operate on. That's its stated purpose in the standard.

For example, you have a function that takes only positive floats, so it throws a domain_error for negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

"Detailed Description
Thrown by the library, or by you, to report domain errors (domain in the mathmatical sense). "

From: http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/~tjuerges/ALMA/STL/html/classstd_1_1domain__error.html

according to this, it should be used if you are given input that does not comply with the constraints you put on your interface. Like say, a function that is supposed to receive a positive value and is given a negative one.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to mathematical domains.

```
float MySqrRoot(float x)
{
    // sqrt is not valid for negative numbers.
    if (x < 0) throw new domain_error;

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that std::domain_error is not used widely. Microsoft for example says, that their own implementation of the C++ standard library does not have any function, that throws this error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/domain-error-class?view=msvc-170

Like `std::out_of_range` and `std::invalid_argument`, `std::domain_error` inherits from `std::logic_error`. So `std::domain_error` ought to be used in contexts, where the program logic gets broken, but not, for example, where something fails because of an unavailable resource (like `std::bad_alloc`, which is thrown, when memory is full, or `std::ios_base::failure`, which is thrown, when files cannot be opened, read or written and the file had been requested to throw on those conditions via its `exceptions()` method).

The Oxford Dictionary explains the word "domain" as: **An area of interest or an area over which a person has control.** https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/domain

So, for example, an error checking implementation of the standard container library might throw a `std::domain_error` here, instead of just ending up in undefined behavior:

```
std::list<std::string> animals = { "Zebra", "Dog", "Rabbit" };
std::list<std::string> plants = { "Maple", "Wheat", "Rose" };
animals.erase(plants.begin());
```

It is a domain error, because the iterator `plants.begin()` is outside of the area of control of the `animals` list.

Keep in mind, though, that you are not required to use the standard C++ library's exceptions and that you may define your own ones instead.